# Add property to Python TypedDict

Tags: python, json, python-typing

I want to have an alias in my `TypedDict` objects to save me from many if/else checks during runtime (`TypedDict` are created during data loading).

I have something like this:

```
class PatientJson(TypedDict):
    id: int
    name: str
```

I want to add `user_id` alias to `PatientJson`, which would return `id`. This would make list comprehensions always point to `user_id` instead of checking which ID exists.

However, with this code:

```
class PatientJson(TypedDict):
    id: int
    name: str

    @property
    def user_id(self) -> int
        return self.id
```

I get an error `Invalid statement in TypedDict definition; expected 'field_name: field_type'`. I've discovered that TypedDicts can't have methods ([link 1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/), [link 2](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5653)). This would also change syntax, since I would have to use `patient.user_id` instead of `patient["user_id"]` and this would be a lot of code changes. How can I do this? I want to avoid adding reduntant fields if possible.

Comment: I have no problem running your code.

Comment: @Johnny It may work, but I have to use dot-based syntax to call patient.user_id instead of patient["user_id"]. This requires a lot of changes in code. I want to use the regular dict access instead, like regular TypedDict.

Answer (score 1):

With a regular `typing.TypedDict`, this is impossible. The typical way to allow accessing something via `obj[key]` would be to implement `__getitem__`, however [the runtime type of a TypedDict object will always be just `dict`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#:%7E:text=the%20runtime%20type%20of%20a%20TypedDict%20object%20will%20always%20be%20just%20dict), so you can't override `__getitem__`.